# Call page_title to Shopify page content

Tags: shopify, liquid

I need to make a large number of similar pages, and I'd like an `<h1>` tag on each page that is identical to the actual page title. I'm not sure how to do this using the page_title Shopify object.

I'm thinking something like `<h1>{{ page_title }}</h1>` in concept but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please check the docs https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/page-title you are correct use {{page_title}}

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I did refer to that's not working.

My code looks like `<h1>{{ page_title }}</h1>` and the page is literally outputting that. It's like it's not passing the object but I'm not sure why

Comment: did you means that this {{ page_title }} is not working ? if yes can you share your url